# Android App showing wrong rep points in Android?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, android-app

I don't know if that is a bug, but when I open an answer/question from Adroid app It is showing That I have 2K rep points, so It's wrong, becouse I need 500 rep point yet, to go over 2K, I've 1.500 RP.

I know that our reputation show the K when we are almost to get the new "K", but It is a bug? I think that the app will show the K when we are close to "K".

Comment: Which android app?

Comment: @ouflak Stack exchange android App.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See also this question on MSE: [Show shortened reputation in rounded down form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/show-shortened-reputation-in-rounded-down-form)

1.500 is rounded in thousands 2K, so the app displays it correctly.

Comment: Well, it's not displaying it correctly or it would be displaying 1,500. Let's just say it's 'working as designed'.